# Finding the file that contains the added path to $PATH

Tags: centos, environment-variables, path

A command has been added to the $PATH, but I cannot find the place that the path has been added to $PATH. Please see that `which` shows the full path to the binary file, however looking into `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` and /`etc/profile.d` returns no result. Please note that the matches in the grep relates to something else.

How can I find where does this path had been added to $PATH?

```
# which mpicc
/opt/openmpi/bin/mpicc
# grep -r openmpi .bash_profile
# grep -r openmpi .bashrc
alias of230='module load openmpi-x86_64; source /export/apps/mechanics/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/etc/bashrc WM_NCOMPPROCS=4 foamCompiler=ThirdParty WM_COMPILER=Gcc48 WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI'
# grep -r openmpi /etc/profile
alias of230='module load openmpi-x86_64; source /export/apps/mechanics/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/etc/bashrc WM_NCOMPPROCS=4 foamCompiler=ThirdParty WM_COMPILER=Gcc48 WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI'
# grep -r openmpi /etc/profile.d/
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.csh:# Add default module definition for rocks-openmpi.
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.csh:# Load the rocks-openmpi module if ROCKS_USER_MODULE_DEF not defined
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.csh:   module -s add rocks-openmpi
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.sh:# load the defaults rocks-openmpi module
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.sh:# Add default module definition for rocks-openmpi.
/etc/profile.d/rocks-hpc.sh:    module add rocks-openmpi 2>/dev/null
```

Please also see the $PATH

```
# echo $PATH
/opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/bio/ncbi/bin:/opt/bio/mpiblast/bin:/opt/bio/EMBOSS/bin:/opt/bio/clustalw/bin:/opt/bio/tcoffee/bin:/opt/bio/hmmer/bin:/opt/bio/phylip/exe:/opt/bio/mrbayes:/opt/bio/fasta:/opt/bio/glimmer/bin:/opt/bio/glimmer/scripts:/opt/bio/gromacs/bin:/opt/bio/gmap/bin:/opt/bio/tigr/bin:/opt/bio/autodocksuite/bin:/opt/bio/wgs/bin:/opt/eclipse:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/maui/bin:/opt/torque/bin:/opt/torque/sbin:/opt/pdsh/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/condor/bin:/opt/condor/sbin:/opt/gridengine/bin/linux-x64:/export/apps/mathematics/matlab2012a/bin:/opt/maui/bin:/export/apps/mathematics/matlab2012a/bin:/export/apps/mathematics/Mathematica/10.3/Executables:/usr/local/chem/g09-64-D01:/home/mahmood/bin:/opt/maui/bin:/opt/torque/bin:/opt/torque/sbin
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What command has been added to `$PATH`? `mpicc`? What is run when you run it and what were you expecting to run? If `mpicc` was added, why are you searching for `openmpi`?

Comment: OK, I see, `openmpi` is part of the target path. It would be nice to edit and clarify that though. Also, please show us the output of `echo $PATH` so we can know what was added.

Answer (score 1):

The machine you're working on seems to have some sort of module system for dynamically making software available, possibly the ["Modules" system](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) (link currently dead because SourceForge is down).

I'm on a system which uses Modules too:

```
$ type mpicc
-ksh93: whence: mpicc: not found
$ module load openmpi
$ type mpicc
mpicc is a tracked alias for /opt/openmpi/1.7.5gcc4.4/bin/mpicc
```

The modules are being looked for in the directories listed in `$LMOD_DEFAULT_MODULEPATH`.  In one of these directories, I find the file `openmpi/default.lua`.  This file is a Lua script.

In the script:

```
local mpipath= "/opt/openmpi/" .. useVer .. usedComp .. compVer
prepend_path("PATH",            pathJoin(mpipath, "bin"))
```

(these are not consecutive lines in the script)

Note: I've never used Modules myself, so I don't know if the setup on my system is Modules operating as default, or if it's a heavily modified local version of it.

Edit: It's either not the same, or a heavily customized version.   The Modules package uses `MODULESHOME` (defaults to `/usr/local/Modules/3.2.7` [according to the manual](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html)). The mechanics would be the same.  There's a module in `$MODULESHOME/modulefiles` somewhere that will set the `PATH` to what you are seeing when you type `module load openmpi` (or if a shell init script does this for you).

Comment: The output of `type mpicc` on my Centos is `mpicc is /opt/openmpi/bin/mpicc` which is different from yours. Also `$LMOD_DEFAULT_MODULEPATH` is empty

Comment: @mahmood The systems are probably administrated by different people, you system and my system, so that's why the paths to `mpicc` are different.  Now that Sourceforge is back up again: have a look at the [modules manual](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html), in particular in te FILES section. If you still can't figure it out, send an email to you sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content of /etc/environment.

This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

Comment: That file is actually empty!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understood what you're asking since you haven't told us what command was added. In any case, I use the following function to search through the usual suspects:

```
grep_bash(){
  grep -H "$@" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
       /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
}
```

In other words, if you're looking for `openmpi`, run:

```
grep -H "openmpi" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
   /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

Note that this will not find it if it is being set in one of the files *sourced* by any of the above. To get a list of sourced files, try:

```
grep -EH "\. |source " ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
~/.bash_aliases    /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* \
/etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

That will return a list of files sourced by your initialization files. You will then need to search through those for your string as well.

Comment: When there is a binary file `/foo/bin/file`, you have to `export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bin`. Your solution doesn't work

Comment: @mahmood yes, I know you need to search for `foo/bin`. As I said, your question wasn't very clear so I didn't know what you should be searching for. If you know that `openmpi` is what you're looking for, then search for that. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, `/opt/opnempi/bin/mpicc` actually exists

Comment: @mahmood I don't doubt that it exists. Please read the answer. I am giving you a list of all the possible files where this could have been added to the `$PATH`. Have you tried my command yet? Did it work?

Comment: Please check the output at http://pastebin.com/wmr6S831